# Need Help fixing touch up paint

Tags: paint

[image]

I recently got my fender fixed and painted by touch up paint. but now how do i blend the new paint with the factory paint? or at least make it look shiny.

Answer (score 1):

Your car looks relatively new.  As such, it uses 2-stage paint: base coat—with the color—and clear coat.  It looks like you only have base coat.  If you paid someone to do that, you got robbed.

Simply polishing it out won't make it as glossy as the rest of the car, but if the base isn't smooth it does need polishing out.  Then you need to hit it with a clear coat.

TBH the color looks wrong, but colors can change after you clear over.  If that was my car, I'd paint the entire panel, then clear over it.

Comment: yea it was painted by spray paint. i got it done from one of my friend. so now can i just put clear coat over it?

Comment: As I said above, I would recommend painting the entire panel, masking off adjacent (unpainted) panels.  But it wouldn't hurt to clearcoat over a section first to see if the color will match after it's all clearcoated.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue is that is not as glossy as the rest of the paintwork.

You can try to use polish to try and buff it out and polish it but be careful as you don't to burn through the paintwork as you'll require more touchup. (This is probably the safer option). If you've got the stamina for it you might be able to polish it by hand, a machine polisher would be a lot easier.

The other option would be apply a couple of layers of clear coat on top of that paintwork but this would again require blending into the rest of the with polish.

There are videos on YouTube where people have achieved what you looking for. Have a watch of those and see what results you can get. Look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKbaXVhvMxE). The latter half of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4vusY2-rkQ) may be helpful as well.

Was the touch up done out of a spray can or a air gun? Or was it done another way? Also, was it done by a garage or done by yourself?